# How i can use image in <LI>

Tags: html, css

I have a `NavBar` and I need images in `<li>`

How can I use `<li>` images?

```
<div id="navBar1">
<ul>
    <!--INVERSE-->
    <li id="navTop4">Caixa</li>
    <li id="navTop3">Documentos -</li>
    <li id="navTop2">Fornecedor -</li>
    <li id="navTop1">Fabrica -</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#navbar1 ul {
    list-style-image:url('mypic.gif');
}
```